# empty check for this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, html

between `head`

```
<head><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
        $.twitter.start({
            searchType:"searchWord", 
            searchObject:"google", 
            lang:"en", 
            live:"live-180", 
            placeHolder:"tweetContainer", 
            loadMSG: "Loading messages...", 
            imgName: "loader.gif", 
            total: 6, 
            readMore: "Read it on Twitter", 
            nameUser:"image", 
            openExternalLinks:"newWindow", 

        });


    });</script></head>
```

between `body`

```
<body>
<div id="tweetContainer"></div>
</body>
```

I want to do an empty check for tweet container as if no tweets then hide Div tweetContainer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
if($("#tweetContainer").eq(0).html() == '')
{
  //this implies there are no tweets. so do whatever you need to
  $("#tweetContainer").hide();
}
```

Hope this helps!

If you need to do this on a regular basis then you could perhaps do

```
function checkTweets()
    {
        if($("#tweetContainer").eq(0).html() == '')
        {
          //this implies there are no tweets. so do whatever you need to
           $("#tweetContainer").hide();
        }
        else
           $("#tweetContainer").show();


    }
    //fire once and then setTime out
    checkTweets();
    setTimeout(checkTweets,100);
```

Comment: but how do I impliment it on body with div id tweetContainer. actually I want hide div if no tweets thats it.

Comment: That code should work on the body with div id tweetContainer. I am editing the code to hide the div. now

Comment: Hi, not sure if my code helped or not but if it did, can you please check the checbox to indicated you accepted my answer? Thanks!